# Facebook App - How do I make my app live?

Tags: android, facebook

I made a mobile app in Android Studios and I'm having some trouble putting in on the Facebook App Store.

I've been looking around everywhere but I can't seem to find out why my Facebook App isn't live. It says the app is live, but when I go to the app page on Facebook, there is no option to play the game.

[image]
[image]

I have made sure that the app is public in the settings menu, because that seemed to be the most common problem. Can anyone help me get my app live on Facebook?

Comment: What kind of app are you making? Is it an mobila app or an web app? Witch platform are you using? ... Please add details to your question (not in a comment)

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn just updated.

Comment: And your code please...

Comment: @NikkiKulyk Don't share appId here or anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting slightly mixed up. If you want to release an Android App (an .apk file) this is usually done through the Google Play Store here: https://play.google.com/apps/publish

If your app (.apk file made in Android Studio) has Facebook integration, for instance Facebook sign in, then you usually create an "app" on the Facebook developer pages and can integrate the Facebook code into your app, but at the end for people to download the app on their phone and play your game - it has to be upload to the Google Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

to make app live on facebook add facebook integeration to the application and follow the steps to make app live provided on [FaceBook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com).

But to make it download by other users u have to place it on playstore.